# Manager can't listen

Tags: communication, united-states

So, gist of the problem: working with manager that can't listen! Literally! During the meeting whenever more junior personnel is asked to provide updates or is talking about some issue , somewhere midway of the statement he would interrupt not letting that person to finish. Another problem (somewhat similar): all meetings now are "virtual" , so during the most recent one while one gentleman was explaining something, he (manager) would start repeat after him, sort of echoing! One important note: such "interruptive" behavior happens regardless of whether the statement was 1-2 sentence of the " whole speech". Originally it was happening to me as well, however, after few "talking over" (*as i had no other choice*) he stopped doing it to me, but continue to other team members. It is prevalent during the updates by more **junior folks**, albeit happens sometimes with more senior guys as well(especially to those who are more shy by nature). **Is there something should be done? What is the most "politically correct" way to send a message , that he has to learn how to listen?**

Comment: “What is the most "politically correct" way to send a message“ Where are you located? Do any of the individuals belong to protected minority groups?

Comment: I am in USA. No-manager is not in "protected minority group", some teammembers are, but race has "no role" in these dynamics.

Comment: Does he comprehends the messages being sent and just the interruptions and the repetition gist are of concern or does he fail to capture the point being conveyed by the speakers?

Comment: Do you think this may be caused by the fact the meeting are now virtual? Some people have poor connections which may make the audio hard to understand (meaning they feel inclined to repeat it), or delayed (which may increase the chance of unintentional interruptions).

Comment: @Mefitico    when message is being interrupted it is impossible to say what this person was trying to convey just based on **partial** message! Sometimes questions are asked, but has the message being completed they (questions) may not even arise !

Comment: @GregoryCurrie it can be one the root causes , but as i recall "very mild" version of such behavior was also happening in the office.

Comment: Why the down-votes? This seems a perfectly cromulent question.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica probably from managers that can't listen and exhibit exact behavior ;-)

Comment: @Jack-Doe , the behavior you describe is pretty common.  Managers (and of course owners) can run companies any way they wish.  Many of the world's more famous entrepreneurs, run meetings in a "do not waste a second" mode; instantly cutting people off (with no explanation) if they want to move on to another issue. Unfortunately, for better or worse, it's not a democracy.

Comment: @Fattie Let me respectfully disagree. I am involved in many activities that are conducted online **only** nowadays! And i specifically paid attention many times to HOW meetings were conducted; that is online meetings with 15-20-50 and even 300 people. And I can assure you - courtesy has not been cancelled! And yes - business owners can do whatever they want, but that works both ways - if you want to alienate your staff , sure , go ahead , interrupt ! How many people do you think would want to work in such environment ?

Comment: @Fattie Managers are usually not company owners, and can be fired for incompetence.

Comment: @gnasher729 Sure, but very rarely.  If, as an underling, you (incredibly) decide to go up against a manager and get him/her fired .. that is all-but unheard of.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a tricky situation.

Unless you are a leader, it's not really your place to "send a message".

If there are more senior people, you should expect them to "stand up for themselves". If they have a problem with being spoken-over, they need to deal with it.

Next time the manager does it to you, it would be appropriate for you to have a private conversation, to ask them not to do it. Maybe they might understand that this particular quirk is frustrating for not just you, but for others.

However, if they are your manager, it's really their prerogative on how meetings work. It's always risky to offer unsolicited advice, so I would refrain from speaking on behalf of the team.

Answer (score 1):

A manager can operate a meeting any way they like within reason.  Is everything getting said that needs saying? If it is its just the rudeness you are dealing with, rudeness will have a way of getting him back if he does it everywhere and all the time, so you can let him hang with his own rope.  But if not everything is getting said that needs saying, you can bring that up and if he reacts you can then let him know it was his talking over people that prevented it from being communicated effectively, maybe he will then get the message